# From distributed processing on several cores to distributed processing on multiple multi-core nodes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, slurm, condor

### Background

In python, I very recently learned how to speed up a serial procedure, with module name `serial_procedure.py`,  by utilizing the 4 cores of my laptop using the `multiprocessing` package yielding the module `multicore_procedure.py`.

### Question

Now, I am about to use a computer cluster with 3 nodes and each node having 4 cores. How would I  speed up the `multicore_procedure.py` by parallelizing it over 3*4 cores of the cluster?

### More specific request

Given that my knowledge in programming and software engineering is very minimal, I would appreciate some explicit example scripts in python to be used with both slurm and condor resource management software systems.  The goal is to automatically detect the 3*4=12 cores available and write a uniform code.

### More information

Sample modules `serial_procdure.py` and `multicore_procedure.py` are provide below. Notice that in every iteration *ell*, an intensive computation is conducted, resulting in a value labeled *total*. A random paragraph  is  written to a given filename under the label *total*. The parallel processes should not mix the paragraphs together, but all processes should write to the same file.

I tried using the mpi4py package to implement mpi, but I don't seem to have gotten it correctly as the resulting performance was similar to serial_procedure.py.

### Serial procedure

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import lorem
import time

# data
high=2**10;
nsamples=2**18;
labels=np.random.randint(0,high,nsamples)

# Serial version
serial_start_time=time.time()
filename='serial.txt'
total=0
with open(filename,'w') as file:
    for ell in labels:
        # supposedly intensive computation:
        for k in range(ell):
            total=total+k; 
        w = csv.writer(file) ;
        w.writerow([total])
        w.writerow(['****'])
        w.writerow(lorem.paragraph())
        total=0;
serial_time=time.time()-serial_start_time;
print('Serial write takes '+ str(serial_time)+' seconds')
# Serial write takes 43.09408092498779 second
```

### Multicore procedure

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import lorem
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

# data
high=2**10;
nsamples=2**18;
labels=np.random.randint(0,high,nsamples)
filename='four_cores_parallel.txt'

# supposedly intensive computation
def worker(ell):
    total=0
    for k in range(ell):
        total=total+k;
    return(total)

multicore_start_time=time.time()
pool=Pool(4);

with open(filename,'w') as file:
    for total in pool.map(worker, labels):
        w = csv.writer(file) ;
        w.writerow([total])
        w.writerow(['****'])
        w.writerow(lorem.paragraph())
multicore_time=time.time()-multicore_start_time;
print('Multicore write takes '+ str(multicore_time)+' seconds')
# Multicore write takes 20.171985149383545 seconds
```

Comment: May I ask where you have the clusters from?

Comment: An update to your question is that I am looking into using Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Could you provide your mpi4py implementation? Strange that you do not get higher performances that your serial version.